# how to add custom rows to CSV file from other csv files

Tags: powershell, csv, row, addition

```
function Add-To-CSV($filename,$result,$action,$keyword,$videoFilename) 
  {  
    $PROGRAM = (Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\LISTOFFILESTOREMOVE.csv).ADDPROGRAMS
    $TYPE = (Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\LISTOFFILESTOREMOVE.csv).TYPE
    $ACTION = (Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\LISTOFFILESTOREMOVE.csv).ACTION
    $newRow = "$result-,$TYPE-,$ACTION-,$PROGRAM-,$keyword-,$text"
    Add-Content $filename $newRow 
       
}

Import-Csv -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\COMPUTERSTHATYOUWANT1.csv | ForEach-Object {

 
$myFileName = "$Search-Text\SW All 1of1 Normal1.csv"
 Add-To-CSV $myFileName $_.PCLIST
}
```

I need to add software for each computer in my list
under the file COMPUTERSTHATYOUWAN1.CSV has the computer list
under LISTOFFILESTOREMOVE.CSV I have the header where I have the names of computer that I want to include for each computer.
$SearchText = Read-Host Prompt 'TYPE THE PATH WHERE THE FILE IS LOCATED'

this is what I get

```
Account , Type , Action , Software
PC1, Workstation , Dell , Soft1 Soft2
PC2, Workstation , Dell , Soft1 Soft2
```

and this is what I need

```
Account , Type , Action , Software
PC1, Workstation , Dell , Soft1
PC1, Workstation , Dell , Soft2
PC2, Workstation , Dell , Soft1
PC2, Workstation , Dell , Soft2
```

Comment: While you keep asking this question, you already had a couple of comments telling you what will certainly not work.. [1] You define a function with 5 parameters, but you only send it 2 parameters when you call it.. [2] variable `$Search` comes from nowhere [3] Your function imports a csv file 3 times over where once is enough. [4] If your file `LISTOFFILESTOREMOVE.csv` contains multiple records, then `$PROGRAM`, `$TYPE` and `$ACTION` will contain **arrays** not single values

Comment: [5] Do not try to write to a CSV using `Add-Content` unless there is no alternative (which there is) [6] Why do you add dashes to each value for the output csv file? [7] variable `$text` is undefined.  **show us some of your (sanitized) csv files**, explain what you need to match between the two and what the desired output should look like.

Comment: thank you for your help @Theo I am new with powershell and still trying to understand it.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate that, but if you want our help (not just code, but hopefully explanation as well), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70341715/edit) your question and put more info in there like I asked in my latest comment.

Comment: $SearchText = Read-Host Prompt 'TYPE THE PATH WHERE THE FILE IS LOCATED'